# Disable eclipse plugin on license expiry?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

What is the best way to disable an eclipse plugin when the license for it expires?

One way ofcourse is to crash the plugin by throwing an exception from the Plugin.start() method but that is very ugly since all the views,etc of the plugin show an exception stack trace.

I obviously want to gracefully disable the plugin instead of crashing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The state of your bundle is decided by framework after it's installed.

- **Installed** it has some issues to be resolved, such as dependencies problem
- **Resolved** installed and no dependency problem
- **Active** if it has activator, and started without exception

So you have to disable the functionalities of your plug-in in your code after the license is expire if you want to use a graceful way to disable it besides throwing exception on the start method of activator.